# How does the parent select which forked child process to communicate with?

Tags: process, pipe, fork

I created several child processes from one parent, and I also created bidirectional pipes between each process and the parent. Now the problem is how can I go back and forth between the child processes and the parent to do different type of works, and let the children communicate with the parent? I was thinking to keep a track of each process's PID, and use it as an identity to switch. But technically, how? Attached is the code that I have so far.

```
struct val
{  int testInt;
  char testChar;
};

int main ()
{   val val1;
    pid_t cpid[3];
    int fd[2], fdd[2];
    int SFC;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{   pipe(fd);
    pipe(fdd);

    cpid[i]=fork();
    if(cpid[i]==0)
    {   cout<<"\nI am a child and my pid is:"<<getpid();
        cout<<"\nMy parent is: "<<getppid();
        SFC=i;
        close(fd[1]);//close fd-pipe write end for child
        read(fd[0], &val1, sizeof(val1));//read from pipe
        close(fdd[0]);
        write(fdd[1], &SFC, sizeof(SFC));
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fdd[1]);

        cout<<"\nChild received value: "<<val1.testInt<<val1.testChar;
        cout<<"\nChild sent value: "<<SFC;
        cout<<endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {   close(fd[0]);//parent close read end of pipe fd
        close(fdd[1]);//parent close write end of pipe fdd
        val1.testInt=4;
        val1.testChar='A';
        write(fd[1], &val1, sizeof(val1));//parent write to fd
        read(fdd[0], &SFC, sizeof(SFC));//parent read from fdd
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fdd[0]);

        wait(NULL);
        cout<<"\nI am the parent and I have this child: "<<cpid[i];
        cout<<"\nParent sent out value: "<<val1.testInt<<val1.testChar;
        cout<<"\nParent received value: "<<SFC<<endl;
    }       
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by *switch*? All your processes are running concurrently, maybe even in parallel. You don't need to switch from one to the other, the three of them are running at the "same time".

Comment: What do you mean by "switch"?  Just write code in the block that the parent runs for the parent's task and write code in the block that the children run for the children's tasks.  *Edit:* ninja'd by 4 seconds...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response from both of you. When I said switch, I mean switch the code block in my coding. Let me readdress my question. How can the parent choose which child to communicate with? Or how do I pick which child to send data to the parent?

Comment: You’re doing the same thing you did in [your other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162449/80216) – forking a child, blowing it away, forking another child, blowing it away, etc…, and then asking how to do parallel processing. If you want your child processes to run concurrently, stop zapping process _n_ before you start process _n_ +1. You understand that, to keep track of the PIDs of three processes, you need to say `pid_t cpid[3];`. But, to communicate with the processes, you need to know the fds of the pipes. Does this suggest anything to you in terms of data storage requirements?

Comment: @G-Man: thank you for your input. I thought I had created 3 child processes running concurrently along with parent in my code posted here. Is it anything wrong with it in terms of this? Also I know to communicate with the children, the parent need to know the fd of each pipe. But since the parent has a unique pair of pipe to each child(means the parent will have multiple fds, but they all look the same in my code), so my question is how does it keep track of the identity of each fds? Should I make the fds a two-dimension array? with the first element tracking the identity of it?

Comment: You did create three child processes, existing asynchronously from their parent. Two big problems: (1) For each child process, you establish pipes, send test messages in both directions, and then immediately close the pipes. So, by the time you’re starting process _n_ +1, you’ve cut off communications with process _n_, and by the time you’ve created all the processes, you have no way to communicate with any of them. (2) You don’t clearly define what the children are supposed to do after they start. … (cont’d)

Comment: (cont’d) … Without trying it myself, I’d guess that they keep on running the `for` loop and spawn third-generation (grandchildren) processes. (3) ***Yes!*** I was hoping you would get the hint. You need a 3×2 array of file descriptors. Or, perhaps better, `struct child_info { pid_t cpid; int fd[2]; }` and then `child_info children[3];`.

Comment: @G-Man:Thank you so much again. Now I am able to let the parent communicate with the child of interest with the 2-D fd array. The above code was just a step-by-step test to see if I could build pipes and send data. Now I am going to add task in the child as well as conditions to specify when to close the pipe.

Comment: @G-Man: for your 2nd point, I've used "break" statement to force the child out of the loop and prevent it from forking more grandchildren (see my above code). Is this appropriate? I remember "break" is not very welcomed in c++, but I am not sure if there is other choice.

Comment: OK, I missed the `break;`. Yes, that should work, and, IMHO, it's perfectly appropriate. Of course, with the code you have now, the `break;` just takes you to the bottom of the `for` loop, which is the end of the program, but I guess you intend to add more functionality there.